# Spring-Data-JPA logs login failed when DB is down

Tags: jpa, spring-data-jpa

Could you please help with this issue, I have Multiple data sources used with in a single Spring batch service, which runs every day @ 7:00 am and I'm using Spring-starter-data-jpa, and the known fact is one of the db will be taken down daily midnight for cleanup, at that time my service is trying to get the connection for every 10s, which is failing to connect until the db is back.

Is there a way i can change the timing or can i use EntityManager for each db and create connection only when i want to query ? I have the working solution something like this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60815886/how-to-connect-multiple-databases-in-jpa)

Could you please help me with a solution, appreciated with the help. Thanks.

Comment: i feel you cannot do that. Since spring or any framework or server for that matter, keeps live database connection pool once the application is up. so it has to make sure the connections are up always. what is the problem you facing? you just want to avoid logs ?

Answer (score 0):

You can tweak that behaviour by configuring your connection pool.
They typically have settings for:

- How many connections to keep open.
- When and how to check if a connection healthy.

By modifying these settings you can control how often a connection pool tries to establish a connection.

Of course it might be that it isn't the connection pool, but some other service trying to access the database.
A health check could be a likely candidate.
If that is the case you'd need check the configuration options of that.